# how to install python bezier on azure

Tags: python, azure, bezier

I want to install the bezier python package in arzue ML. Unfortunately I get this error message:

```
SolverProblemError

  Because no versions of bezier match >2021.2.12,<2022.0.0
   and bezier (2021.2.12) depends on numpy (>=1.20.1), bezier (>=2021.2.12,<2022.0.0) requires numpy (>=1.20.1).
  And because azureml-dataset-runtime (1.31.0) depends on numpy (<=1.19.3), bezier (>=2021.2.12,<2022.0.0) is incompatible with azureml-dataset-runtime (1.31.0).
  And because azureml-dataset-runtime (1.31.0) depends on azureml-dataset-runtime (1.31.0)
   and no versions of azureml-dataset-runtime match >1.31.0,<1.32.0, bezier (>=2021.2.12,<2022.0.0) is incompatible with azureml-dataset-runtime (>=1.31.0,<1.32.0).
  And because azureml-defaults (1.31.0) depends on azureml-dataset-runtime (>=1.31.0,<1.32.0)
   and no versions of azureml-defaults match >1.31.0,<2.0.0, bezier (>=2021.2.12,<2022.0.0) is incompatible with azureml-defaults (>=1.31.0,<2.0.0).
  So, because demo-add depends on both azureml-defaults (^1.31.0) and bezier (^2021.2.12), version solving failed.

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/puzzle/solver.py:241 in _solve
      237│             packages = result.packages
      238│         except OverrideNeeded as e:
      239│             return self.solve_in_compatibility_mode(e.overrides, use_latest=use_latest)
      240│         except SolveFailure as e:
    → 241│             raise SolverProblemError(e)
      242│ 
      243│         results = dict(
      244│             depth_first_search(
      245│                 PackageNode(self._package, packages), aggregate_package_nodes`
```

Seems like there is some dependency clash. Can anyone help me by solving this problem?

Comment: what versions do you have pegged in your requirements.txt or whatever flavour of dependency file you're using (in which case, which dependency manager do you use). As per the text, azureml-dataset-runtime needs numpy 1.19.3 or earlier, whereas the version of bezier you're using requires a numpy that's newer than that, so: use an older version of bezier if you absolutely need azureml-dataset-runtime?

Comment: I'm using poetry and not installing azureml-dataset-runtime itself but other azure packages I need (azureml-core, azureml-pipeline and azure-storage-blob). I guess it belongs to the dependency of one of those azure packages. I understand the error itself but I don't know how to fix it properly. If I install bezier via pip it works, but I think in that case bezier is installed globally not in the current virtual environment if I'm not wrong...

Comment: if you're in an activated virtualenv, there is no "globally". If you're using poetry, check poetry.lock to see which version of bezier you're installing. If using pip, freeze your pip requirements to a requirements.txt and then check that to determine which version is getting used.

Comment: Ah ok, if there is no 'globally' I don't know what I did there. On the website of [bezier](https://pypi.org/project/bezier/#files) all versions require `numpy 1.20.1` which will cause the clash. I need `numpy 1.19.3` or lower. I somehow made to install `bezier` (don't ask me how). I am able to run `model.py` in azure workspace which imports the library `bezier`. But if I generate `Experiment` and `ScriptRunConfig` objects to run the file via an experiment in azure the error again occurs: `No module named bezier`. I'm wondering if I'm forced to use conda environment instead of poetry.

Comment: EDIT: I didn't make anything... in poetry I even have to install individually all azure packages I want to use. In doing so I still get the same error. Is there a way to change the dependency of `bezier` library manually to `numpy 1.19.3`?

Comment: if you don't have a py-project.toml, re-initialise your project as per https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#initialising-a-pre-existing-project, and then you can control which versions get installed.

Comment: I have a py-project.toml, so I modified the dependency of the `bezier` in poetry.lock from `numpy` version 1.20.1 to 1.19.3. Seems like the packages are not read from the toml file... suddenly the matplotlib file could not be found which already was added to poetry environment. So I generated a `requirements.txt` file with the libraries I need. The corresponding error says `The BEZIER_INSTALL_PREFIX environment variable must be set.` Don't know what that means... The exception itself is called `CondaEnvException: Pip failed` 

PS I'm sorry if I don't get things fast, I'm very new to AzureML

Comment: So far nothing about this is related to Azure, it's just dependency version conflict management, and at this point I'd strongly recommend you read through that whole `poetry` page I linked to, start to bottom, before trying to apply anything it talks about - read it first, _then_ start editing things, because poetry absolutely uses `pyproject.toml` (note: there are no hyphens in that file name).